# Add arrow functions to table cells with row and column as parameter

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to call a function via arrow function in javascript for all cells in a table and add the row and column of the cell as parameter. But my solution doesn't work:

```js
setTableListener() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tableName"), row, column;

    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
            var cell = table.rows[i].cells[j];
            row = cell.parentElement.rowIndex;
            column = cell.cellIndex;
            cell.onclick = () => this.turn(row, column);
        }
    }
}

turn(row, column) {
    console.log(row + " " + column)
}
```

The output is alsways `2 2` for a talbe size 3x3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶c̶a̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶u̶n̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶p̶e̶r̶t̶i̶e̶s̶ ̶`r̶o̶w̶I̶n̶d̶e̶x̶` ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶`c̶e̶l̶l̶I̶n̶d̶e̶x̶` ̶b̶e̶g̶i̶n̶s̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶0̶.̶ ̶A̶c̶c̶o̶r̶d̶i̶n̶g̶l̶y̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶r̶d̶ ̶r̶o̶w̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶c̶o̶l̶u̶m̶n̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶2̶.̶

Update.

Excuse me for my inattentiveness.
When your `onclick` function is called, method `turn` refers to `row` and `cell` variables, which was overwritten by the last loop's iteration.

How to fix it?
You need to place initialization of variables `row` and `cell` and `onclick` function setting in [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

For example:

```
cell.onclick = (() => {
    // Closure starts here. Now, method turn will be called with variables which was defined down here.
    var row = cell.parentElement.rowIndex;
    var column = cell.cellIndex;
    return () => this.turn(row, column);
})();
```

Here we've created self-executing anonymous function which contains initialization of `row` and `cell` variables, which contains needed values. Also, here we've returned function which will be set as onclick handler, and our handler contains call of turn `method` to which transferred variables `row` and `cell`.

Accordingly, every onclick handler inner `turn` method call have passed own `row` and `cell` variables which was initialized in closure.

Comment: Yes but the problem is: I want to get the row and column of a cell i clicked on and call the method with the values as parameter. Now I get the same output for every cell I click on.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is to attach 'unique' `onclick` event listener to each cell. So, try this instead

`cell.addEventListener('click', this.turn.bind(this, row, column))`

Or,

`cell.onclick = this.turn.bind(this, row, column);`